# Why the work done by pressure is equal to $p_1A_1v_1\cdot \Delta t - p_2A_2v_2\cdot \Delta t$ in the derivation of Bernoulli's equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, work, flow, bernoulli-equation

[image]

In [deriving](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_40.html) Bernoulli's equation, it is assumed that the work done by pressure on a chunk of fluid entering the pipe at point $1$ and leaving at point $2$ during a time $\Delta t$ is

$$W_{p}=p_1A_1v_1\cdot \Delta t - p_2A_2v_2\cdot \Delta t.$$

$v_1\cdot \Delta t$ is the distance traveled by chunk entering the inlet, and  $v_2\cdot \Delta t$ is the distance traveled by *another* chunk leaving the outlet.

[image]

If we denote the the thickness of the entering chunk by $\Delta x _{1}$, then shouldn't the work done around point $1$ be  $$( p|_{1}-p|_{1+\Delta x _{1}})|\cdot A_{1} \cdot v_1\cdot \Delta t ~~~~~?$$

As opposed to $$p_1A_1v_1\cdot \Delta t, $$

which seems to completely dismiss the pressure at the other side of the ongoing chunk (i.e. the pressure at a distance $\Delta x_{1}$ from point $1$). The same goes for $p_2A_2v_2\cdot \Delta t$, where this time it's the pressure at a distance $\Delta x_{2}$ from the outlet (point $2$) that gets dismissed.

Comment: Work is $F\cdot \Delta x$. Force is $P\cdot A$, and $\Delta x = v\cdot \Delta t$...

Comment: With all due respect, I don't see how restating what work, force, and displacement are help answer the question.

Comment: Okay, it answers the title of the question. The answe to the REAL question is... check that each "chunk" is going to cancel out with the next one. In the end, you only have two contributions: the entrance and the exit. The intermediate ones cancel out